# Python | return something similar to "os.get_terminal_size"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to implement something similar to the return of `os.get_terminal_size`

```
print(myFunction())

myFunction(a=1, b=2)

print(myFunction().a)    # 1

print(myFunction().b)    # 2
```

example:

```
import os
os.get_terminal_size()
'os.terminal_size(columns=169, lines=40)'

os.get_terminal_size().columns
169

type(os.get_terminal_size)
'<class 'os.terminal_size'>'
```

How can I do that?

Comment: last linesshows you that it is `class`, not function - so you have to create `class` , not function. And may need method `__str__` to format printed result. It also get values from system, not as arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type(os.get_terminal_size)` shows that it is a class, not function.

First line also shows that it has method `__str__` to display formatted text with values

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.columns = 169
        self.lines = 40

    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyClass(columns={}, lines={})'.format(self.columns, self.lines)

print(MyClass())
# MyClass(columns=169, lines=40)

print(MyClass().columns)
# 169
```

---

**EDIT:**

It also doesn't get arguments but if you want to arguments then you would need

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, columns=169, lines=40):
        self.columns = columns
        self.lines = lines

    def __str__(self):
        return 'MyClass(columns={}, lines={})'.format(self.columns, self.lines)

print(MyClass())
# MyClass(columns=169, lines=40)

print(MyClass(columns=1, lines=2))
# MyClass(columns=1, lines=2)
```

But it can't keep values - it would need instance of class to keep them.

```
print(MyClass(columns=1, lines=2).columns)
# 1

print(MyClass().columns)
# 169

my_instance = MyClass(columns=1, lines=2)
print(my_instance.columns)
# 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to implement `get_terminal_size` yourself in a different way.

`shutil.get_terminal_size` wraps `os.get_terminal_size` and basically performs an optimization where it looks up your `${COLUMNS}` and `${LINES}` environment variables as a shortcut. Failing the lookup, it defers to `os.get_terminal_size`. Its source code is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/94e165096fd65e8237e60de570fb609604ab94c9/Lib/shutil.py#L1302).

As for the implementation of `os.get_terminal_size`, it is written in `c` and under the hood leverages either [ioctl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ioctl) or [conio.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h). The code lives [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c0c325453a175350e3c18ebb10cc10c37f9595c/Modules/posixmodule.c#L12217).